# Float difference in string and int format. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision, floating-accuracy, nanotime

I need the current time with nanosec.
As string `"%.9f" % float_time` it is 1502872986.6536936**76**. You can see 76 at the end.
If I try to write the same time as int `int(float_time*10**9)`, it will be 15028729866536936**96** and 96 at the end. Why? And which is the right way to get nano format?

```
from time import time

float_time = time()
print("float_time:", float_time)
int_nano_time = int(float_time*10**9)
print("int_nano_time:", int_nano_time)
str_nano_time = "%.9f" % float_time
print("str_nano_time:", str_nano_time)
```

> float_time: 1502872986.6536937
>
> int_nano_time: 1502872986653693696
>
> str_nano_time: 1502872986.653693676

**Solution:**

```
time.monotonic()
```

> float_time: 536596.296
>
> int_nano_time: 536596296000000
>
> str_nano_time: 536596.296000000

Comment: [python uses IEEE-754 double precision](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), hence have only 53 bits in significand part which is about 15-17 decimal digits (1502872986.6536936 has 17 significant digits, the rest is just noise)

Comment: @Elena it is highly probable that the `time()` returned isn't correct to nanosecond precision.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is it possible to get nanosec in int in python? In C++ world they don't have the problem, because they get it in 64bits int. They don't meet the IEEE754.

Comment: @Elena as I've tried to explain, if you use the time returned by `time()` its precision doesn't matter, because *both* instants 1502872986653693696 and 15028729866536937 occurred *while* the `time()` function was fetching the timestamp and converting the timestamp to a floating point object etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct within the IEEE754 double precision of ~15.7 decimal digits. The reason is that the multiples of ten cannot be produced exactly, so while multiplying by `2 ** 10` is exact, multiplying by `5 ** 10` will have rounding errors again, and that's why the last numbers differ.

```
'1502872986.653693675994873046875000000000'
>>> "%.30f" % (1502872986.653693676 * 10 ** 9)
'1502872986653693696.000000000000000000000000000000'
```

The hex representations of these 2 floating point numbers are wildly different:

```
>>> (1502872986.653693676 * 10 ** 9).hex()
'0x1.4db4704d00617p+60'
>>> (1502872986.653693676).hex()
'0x1.6650166a9d61ep+30'
```

As for the time returned from the `time()` call - well it is highly probable that should the computer have a timer that gives a timestamp with high enough precision *any* time value will be between the exact time `time()` was called and when it returned:

```
>>> (time() - time()) * 10 ** 9
-715.2557373046875
>>> (time() - time()) * 10 ** 9
-953.67431640625
>>> (time() - time()) * 10 ** 9
-953.67431640625
```

your error was 20 nanoseconds, but the time difference between 2 consecutive timestamps returned from `time()` call is 700-100 nanoseconds on my computer.